# Why is it better to catch exception high in the callstack rather as soon as it can be handled?

Tags: architecture, exception

I've read in a couple of places that its better to catch exceptions higher up in the callstack but I havent been able to find the justification for this statement.

**Scott Hanselman**: [Remember that Application_Error exists. Catch exceptions as high as you can, not as low.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GoodExceptionManagementRulesOfThumbBackToBasicsEdition.aspx#7417e126-6c6c-4e7c-97bc-5e0f3145bbe6)

I believe exception should be caught where it can be handled, high or low doesn't matter. Is it not true? If not then why?

Please add an example with your answer if possible.

Thanks

Comment: I have similar questions. @Hasan Khan, what do you mean by *handled* , where you write "...exception should be caught where it can be *handled*..."?  To *handle* a caught exception, do you mean to log the exception, catch & eat the exception, `throw;`,  wrap & throw it as InnerException, change any particular state, ... ?

Comment: @T.Webster by handled I mean to act on the exception. I.e. retry the operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should catch an exception at the point in the code where you can do something about it. Often, the code that generates the exception isn't in a position to deal with the problem, but the method that called that code, or the method that called the method that called that code, can handle the problem gracefully.

Say you've got some code that tries to open a file and read some data, and it generates an exception if the file doesn't exist. Code at that scope can't do much but bail, but several frames up the call stack a calling method might say "Oh, okay, got an exception. I'll try this alternate file instead" or "I guess that file didn't exist, so I'll go ahead and create a new one."

This is really one of the great benefits of exceptions: they free the developer from having to handle every possible error condition immediately. You can write code with the expectation that it's going to work most of the time, and your code doesn't need to be cluttered up with a lot of error handling. As long as you advertise which exceptions you might throw, you can make the code higher up in the call stack deal with problems in a way that's appropriate to whatever that code is trying to do.

Comment: It's hard to say anything concrete without some context. "its better to catch exceptions higher up" -- okay, but higher up than what? And what are the sources that wrote that? What's the context that they're talking about. One or two levels up may not be enough in some situations, it might be perfect in others. There's no rule -- do what makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe exception should be caught where it can be handled

Absolutely.  The point is that lower in the callstack you are less likely to know how to handle it.

Comment: @Hasan: an example is a GUI around a database. The database code throws exceptions when it encounters errors; the GUI can present these error messages to the user, perhaps with various options for fixing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should catch exceptions in 2 situations:

1. You know what to do with the exception
2. You're wrapping exception with different one